# Changing a file name, without rewrite it

Tags: java, file

I am trying to write a code that just changes the file name without reading and writing it with a different name, is there any built in function for that? I tried to search for

and if not, the best way would be rewriting it with a new name?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.

Comment: sorry gor the idiotic question, i was looking for a renameTo function

Comment: That's not idiotic question. It's a valid question, but a minimal research efforts would have gave you the answer quickly.

Comment: i did research, but because of ,y not very good english i didnt find an answer, ill be glad if someone that can, will edit my question so it would be better.

Comment: [Welcome to SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), I'm sure you'll be involved in helpful topics here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about the [File.renameTo(File dest)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) function?

Comment: +1 for questioning the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
new File("MyFile.txt").renameTo(new File("MyNewFile.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

> [**renameTo**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29)
>
> `public boolean renameTo(File dest)`
>
> Renames the file denoted by this abstract pathname.
>
> Many aspects of the behavior of this method are
>   inherently platform-dependent: The rename operation might not be able
>   to move a file from one filesystem to another, it might not be atomic,
>   and it might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract
>   pathname already exists. The return value should always be checked to
>   make sure that the rename operation was successful.
>
> **Parameters:** dest - The new abstract pathname for the named file
>
> **Returns:** true if and only if the renaming succeeded; false otherwise
>
> **Throws:** SecurityException - If a security manager exists and its
>   SecurityManager.checkWrite(java.lang.String) method denies write
>   access to either the old or new pathnames NullPointerException - If
>   parameter dest is null